# Vibrate until the button is pressed and stops vibrating when the button is unpressed (or the finger is taken off)

Tags: java, android, vibration

I am planning to program a button in such a way that when the button is pressed, vibration starts and keeps on vibrating until the finger is up or button is unpressed.

I am using OnTouchListener for this purpose.

My code is as follows:

```
package com.example.vibrator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Vibrator vibrator;

        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(MainActivity.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    vibrator.vibrate(60000);
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    vibrator.cancel();
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem in this code is that it keeps on vibrating and when the finger is up, the vibration does not stop nor cancelled.

P.S. I have used the permission in manifest.

Comment: Check With `Log` if your `else if` is called. Or maybe something different handles the motion up event therefore your onTouchListener on uour button won't receive the event. Also check which int you get from action when releasing your finger from the screen

Comment: Thankyou so much bro (yshahak). looking forward for your more support in the comming future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**: corrected code:

try this:

```
int action = event.getActionMasked();

if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    long[] pattern = { 0, 200, 0 }; //0 to start now, 200 to vibrate 200 ms, 0 to sleep for 0 ms.
    vibrator.vibrate(pattern, 0); // 0 to repeat endlessly.
} else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
    vibrator.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Please insert Log.i("event", event.toString()); below int action, to check execution flow.

Comment: I think I figured it for you. Try the corrected code in my answear.

Comment: You need a pattern as @yshahak wrote.